# Como alterar uma um registro no Mongo através de uma função e update node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Estou com um problema. Tenho um conjunto de dados dentro do Mongo, um json que foi retornado de um request da url `pa/` com

```
app.get('/pa', function (req, res) {
    paController.list(function(resp) {
        res.jsonp(resp);
    });
});
```

parecido com esse:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "579a865cb742f206523961af",
    "codPA": 150440,
    "latPA": 5345345,
    "lonPA": 5345345,
    "qtdPesPA": 37,
    "qtdDiaPA": 0,
    "adminPA": "Caio",
    "nomePA": "RIACH�O 1",
    "capacPA": 8,
    "cidadePA": "Caruaru",
    "estadoPA": "PE",
    "statusPA": true,
    "__v": 0,
    "cadPA": "2016-08-04T19:02:26.616Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": "579a865cb742f206523961b0",
    "codPA": 150441,
    "latPA": 5345345,
    "lonPA": 5345345,
    "qtdPesPA": 47,
    "qtdDiaPA": 0,
    "adminPA": "Caio",
    "nomePA": "RIACH�O 1",
    "capacPA": 8,
    "cidadePA": "Caruaru",
    "estadoPA": "PE",
    "statusPA": true,
    "__v": 0,
    "cadPA": "2016-08-04T19:02:26.616Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": "579a865cb742f206523961b1",
    "codPA": 150442,
    "latPA": 5345345,
    "lonPA": 5345345,
    "qtdPesPA": 188,
    "qtdDiaPA": 0,
    "adminPA": "Caio",
    "nomePA": "RIACH�O 1",
    "capacPA": 10,
    "cidadePA": "Caruaru",
    "estadoPA": "PE",
    "statusPA": true,
    "__v": 0,
    "cadPA": "2016-08-04T19:02:26.617Z"
  }
]
```

Sendo que estou com uma função de regressão, para alterar o registro de todos campos qtdDiaPA. Não estou conseguindo fazer uma função de atualize o campo em questão para cada registro dentro do Mongo.

Eu quero uma função do node que aplique no campo qtdDiaPA uma regressão linear que foram calculado deste mesmo conjunto de dados. Eu invoco esse calculo através de uma requisição, porém quero coloca-la em um timeout de 6 em 6 horas para calcular a regressão e em seguida, aplica-la no banco no registro qtdDiaPA que recebe o cálculo da regressão e atualiza outra função que vai verificar se alguns parâmentros de data do conjunto Entrega que contém um campo de data onde será feito um calculo de diferença da data atual para os dias calculado e inseridos em qtdDiaPA.

Em resumo, eu quero pegar um json, acessar seu valores, altera-los. Depois colocar de volta em um objeto e mandar para ser atualizado no banco com o qtdDiaPA recebendo o calculo da minha regressão para cada codPA no mongo. É isso.

A função que tentei desenvolve é esta, mas ela não realizar as modificações no arquivo.

```
exports.atua = function(data, palavra) {

    var calcA = parseFloat(palavra[0]);
    var calcB = parseFloat(palavra[1]);
    var erroP = parseFloat(palavra[2]);
    var consDia = parseFloat(palavra[3]);
    var result;

    var codPA = 0;
    var latPA = 0;
    var lonPA = 0;
    var qtdPesPA = 0;
    var qtdDiaPA = 0;
    var adminPA = 0;
    var nomePA = 0;
    var capacPA = 0;
    var cidadePA = 0;
    var estadoPA = 0;
    var statusPA = 0;
    var cadPA;

    var test = data.paa;

    for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        var ta = test[i];
        var linhaY = at.capacPA / (at.qtdPesPA * consDia);
        ta.codPA = ta.codPA;
        ta.latPA = ta.latPA;
        ta.lonPA = ta.lonPA;
        ta.qtdPesPA = ta.qtdPesPA;
        ta.qtdDiaPA = Math.round(((linhaY - ((calcA * ta.capacPA) + calcB) + erroP) + erroP + linhaY) * erroP / 10);
        ta.adminPA = ta.adminPA;
        ta.nomePA = ta.nomePA;
        ta.capacPA = ta.capacPA;
        ta.cidadePA = ta.cidadePA;
        ta.estadoPA = ta.estadoPA;
        ta.statusPA = ta.statusPA;
        ta.cadPA = new Date
        result = ta.qtdDiaPA;
    }
    return result;
};


/*
ta.save(function(error, pa) {

    if (error) {
        result = ({
            error: 'Valor de campo inválido'
        });
    } else {
        result = (pa);
    }

});
*/
```

Tá difícil, não tenho muita experiência em JS e Node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui fica uma ajuda na lógica da função para modificar os dados que estás a receber e retornar um json na mesma, modificado:

```
module.exports = function (data, palavra) {

    var calcA = parseFloat(palavra[0]);
    var calcB = parseFloat(palavra[1]);
    var erroP = parseFloat(palavra[2]);
    var consDia = parseFloat(palavra[3]);

    data.paa = data.paa.map(function(teste){
        var linhaY = at.capacPA / (at.qtdPesPA * consDia);
        teste.qtdDiaPA = Math.round(((linhaY - ((calcA * teste.capacPA) + calcB) + erroP) + erroP + linhaY) * erroP / 10);
        teste.cadPA = new Date();
        return teste.qtdDiaPA;
    });
    return data;
};
```

Basicamente estás a modificar somente `data.paa` daí que usei o `data.paa = data.paa.map(function(teste){` parta trocar essa array pelos novos resultados.

Aqui na suécia está na hora de dormir. Amanhã posso dar uma olhada aqui se conseguiste resolver o problema. Mas como disseste que tinhas [dificuldade na lógica da função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145562/como-alterar-uma-um-registro-no-mongo-atrav%C3%A9s-de-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-update-node?noredirect=1#comment300389_145562), aqui fica.

Comment: Só posso agradecer imensamente sua ajuda! Muito obrigado Sergio... Tenho que entregar este trabalho até meia noite de amanhã... Amanhã, tem mais dúvidas!

Comment: Encontrei o erro que me custou...

var paSchema = mongoose.Schema({

        codPA: Number,
        latPA: Number,
        lonPA: Number,
        qtdPesPA: Number,
        qtdDiaPa: Number,
        adminPA: String,
        nomePA: String,
        capacPA: Number,
        cidadePA: String,
        estadoPA: String,
        statusPA: Boolean,
        cadPA: Date

    });

Não acredito... Acontece! :)

Comment: @HENNINGSUMMER conseguiste então por isso a funcionar?

Comment: Sim @Sergio! Sua ajuda foi importante. Agora, estou com outra dúvida... Como consigo falar com você, para ver se consegues me ajudar?

Comment: @HENNINGSUMMER eu ajudo aqui no stackoverflow, fora disso não tenho tempo. Assim todos aprendem. Se a minha resposta resolveu o problema, marca como aceite e lança nova pergunta com o novo problema.

Comment: fiz uma nova pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145706/como-invocar-uma-url-no-node-para-dentro-de-uma-pagina-html agradeço sua ajuda desde já.